# Require module with that executes later on node

Tags: javascript, node.js

In index.js I have a require function and some extra stuff right bellow.

The required module has a delay in execution;

index.js

```
console.log('1')
var delay_function = require('./delay_function')
console.log('2')
```

delay_function.js

```
    var fetch = require('node-fetch');

    fetch('http://example.com/api').then(function(res){
        console.log('wuhu');
    });
```

The result of the two scripts above is:

```
    1
    2
    wuhu
```

instead of:

```
    1
    wuhu
    2
```

I am new to node and trying to understand how the require function works, but the documentation is so scattered that it's overwhelming.

How can I make the two scripts execute in the order I need them too?

Comment: May be be you need to look into [async-waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is perfectly normal.

In your delay_function.js you start a fetch operation in the background, we say the call is non-blocking. It allows node to do other things while the data is begin fetched.

Here is a solution to your problem:

delay_function.js

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var task = fetch('http://example.com/api');        
task.then(function(res){
    console.log('wuhu');
});

module.exports = task;
```

index.js

```
console.log('1')
require('./delay_function').then(function(res) {
  console.log('2')
}
```

**Explaination**

The delay_function.js, when required start fetching the result, display wuhu when the fetch is done and returns (using `module.exports`) the background task, so to say. In the index you retrieve the background task and display 2 when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is non blocking so when you require, it doesn't block the execution and display 2 right away. when fetch finish, it display `wuhu`.

To do that in order, you can use Promise.

Basically it will look like this

```
doThis().then(doThat)
```